# Map network drive to unavailable network share

Tags: windows, docker, network-share

I'm trying to build windows container with predefined network drives.

When I add `RUN NET USE Z: \\myfileserver\sharedfolder`, I get error:

> System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found.

Is it possible to map the network drive even if the path is unavailable at the time?

It will be available when I run the container

Comment: nope it must be alive

Answer (score 0):

No, don't do that. Use a script. Even better, prefer shortcuts over drive letters.